# How to get a mask from blending modes

Tags: adobe-photoshop, transparency, blending, blend-modes

So it's a bit complicated but here is the gist... I made a design using blending modes with a background texture of cardboard. The idea is that the design will get printed directly on the cardboard so now I would need to basically extract those images and get them into a .PNG with transparency. But whenever I do that the white still stays left behind from not having a texture underneath it. I tried using a mixture of masking and blend but the white areas stay behind and it just looks so much worse.

Here are some screenshots so that you can see what the problem is.
[image: How it should look]

[image: The problem]

Comment: Why white on your design is a problem? It's not like the printer would print with white color, wouldn't it?

Comment: I can only see this is a problem if you really are printing with white ink in some areas. The green area seems totally untouched by the cardboard texture. Normally you don't print white ink so the green area will also get darker and have cardboard texture. It *is* possible to get that transparency though, if you still think it's needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure you are planning your print the right way.

As I understand your project will be printing black and green on the cardboard:

[image]

So you should separate your files, a plate for the black and a plate for the green.

[image]

But if you want white over green, you need a white plate that will look simply the same as the black plate, using white opaque ink. There is a chance that you can use a flat green color, without the shape of the pot. Probably not. It depends on the absorption of the cardboard and how opaque the inks are.

[image]

You do not need a transparent PNG, no. You need a black and white plate.

---

Keep in mind that cardboard absorbs ink like water on a desert, so make some tests first.

There is a chance you need to "darken" your white plate.

[image]